# How to populate field in all objects of an array response?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a User model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  _id: generated
})
```

and a Project model:

```
const projectSchema = new Schema({
  owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  name: String,
  _id: generated
})
```

I am using a request to get all projects, and would like to then populate the 'owner' field of each project with the corresponding user (or, even better, their username)

```
Project.find()
  .populate('owner')
  .then((allProjects) => {
    console.log(allProjects);
    res.status(200).json(allProjects);
})
```

The response from the find(), as seen in the console.log() is an array of objects, on which populate seems to have had no effect:

```
[{
  _id: 4kal5mah5lam6la2lam40am3,
  owner: 28eqo29roqi5lqmdka91ma01,
  name: Project1
 },
 {
  _id: 0akm40am593na7n4fnau25a,
  owner: 85jan5l60oq23la1p07d8q2,
  name: Project2
 }]
```

I've tried many things with the populate call and its parameter but to no effect. The code runs, just doesn't populate the field. Any ideas?

Many thanks!